# Conditional div class doesn't echo, only the variable within does

Tags: php

Is there any reason why this is happening due to the following code? All that gets displayed is the variable , i.e the image.

```
<?php $featured_image = the_post_thumbnail();?>
    <?php if (is_page(7) || is_page(12))
        echo '<div class="featured_image">' . $featured_image . '</div>'
    ?>
```

Comment: what's the output from this? Can you post the source html of the output you are getting?

Comment: Are you using this inside The Loop? See codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail . Use get_the_post_thumbnail($id, $size, $attr ) instead to get the featured image for any post.

Comment: Try to use open an close brackets. `if (is_page(7) || is_page(12)){` ... `}`

Comment: typo? `echo '<div class="featured_image">' . $featured_image . '</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $featured_image = the_post_thumbnail();

    if (is_page(7) || is_page(12)) { 
        echo '<div class="featured_image">' . $featured_image . '</div>';
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function itself echos the img: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

try:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && (is_page(7) || is_page(12))) {
        echo '<div class="featured_image">';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</div>';
    } 
?>
```

What you are seeing is the return value of the echo function.

Comment: Unexpected syntax { . Why would it be unexpected here? Also @Steve - the last bracket } causes the same error too. Thanks for the quick responses btw.

Comment: Sorry, bad syntax. I needed a close parenthesis. Is fixed. Try again.